# "A non numeric value encountered" on a line with just a number

Tags: php

I don't know what I changed but suddenly I'm getting an error on the code that worked before:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs.apps\DeSplinterRekenen\Code\addAnswer.php on line 32

These are line 31, 32 and 33, I put the 1 in a seperate line to point out that the error is actually pointed on the 1:

```
header("Location: assignment.php?assign=" . $_SESSION['activeAssign'] . "&question=" . $_SESSION['activeQuestion'] +
    1
);
```

Why is php saying a literal 1 is non-numeric?
I've tried this and it worked, but it just seems weird I have to do it this way:

```
$var = $_SESSION['activeQuestion'] + 1;
header("Location: assignment.php?assign=" . $_SESSION['activeAssign'] . "&question=" . $var);
exit();
```

Comment: Have you tried `"&question=" . ($_SESSION['activeQuestion'] + 1)` as it is assuming you want to do the `+` on the whole of the left hand side.

Comment: It's because of operator precedence and associativity.

Comment: @NigelRen Ohh, that works. A confusing error though... If it thinks I want to add the 1 to the entire string on the left it should give an error saying it expects the string on the left to be a numeric value right? Not the 1... A 1 is obviously a numeric value...

Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` and `.` have the same precedence, and they're left-associative. So `($a . $b + $c)` is equivalent to `($a . $b) + $c`, not `$a . ($b + $c)`.

In your case, the concatenations don't produce a number, so when you try to add `1` to it, you get an error. You can use parentheses to specify the desired grouping.

```
header("Location: assignment.php?assign=" . $_SESSION['activeAssign'] . "&question=" . ($_SESSION['activeQuestion'] + 1));
```